# How to implement event handler in a separate file and attach it by using dependency injection?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, discord.net

I'm using Discord.Net to create a C# Discord bot. My application is using Dependency Injection and in the Program.cs file I have access to the singleton instance of `DiscordSocketClient`.

This instance provides many events e.g.

```
discordSocketClient.UserJoined += async socketGuildUser =>
{
    // do things here
};
```

This seems to be a more C# related question. I want to create separate files with one event handler per file to keep the code organized. A sample event handler could look like

```
public class UserJoinedHandler
{
    // Use the constructor to get access to services by using DI 

    public Task OnUserJoined(SocketGuildUser socketGuildUser)
    {
        // Do things here
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

---

What is the best / easiest way to attach this event listener? The first solution coming to my mind would be to register this handler as a singleton service

`serviceCollection.AddSingleton<UserJoinedHandler>();`

and in my Program.cs file I could then do this

`discordSocketClient.UserJoined += serviceProvider.GetService<UserJoinedHandler>().OnUserJoined;`

---

Are there any better solutions to register handlers? E.g. using reflection or annotations like `[ThisClassHandlesTheUserJoinedEvent]` and let the client search for those by adding an extension method like `discordSocketClient.SearchForEventHandlingAnnotations()` ?

I know this sounds like overengineering but this project is a big one and I like organized code.

Comment: What kind of pluggable architecture are you envisaging that will need this complexity?

Comment: Inject the client into the handler and subscribe to the event.

Comment: I don't know yet but I was simply hoping for a "most optimized" way :)

Comment: @Nikosi but then I have to inject all those handlers somewhere to initialize them, no?

Comment: Create a common interface for handlers, and have a hosted service that takes the handlers so that they can be initialized at startup

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a half answer/half comment.

Be careful not to overuse dependency injection. It's a great tool to help you avoid tight coupling in your code and make testing of dependent services easier but it's not meant to help you organize your code.

In your case you don't really have a dependent service - i.e. a service that depends on your handlers. This means there's really nothing to inject them into. Yes, you could create a wrapper class you can inject into that collects and registers all the handlers but does it really add any value to you?

If I were you I would just have a helper class to `RegisterClientHandlers` and then subscribe your handlers to all the events in there. If you then down the line think you need to be able to test different combinations of handlers (say `UserJoinedHandler_v2` together with `UserLeftHandler_v1`), then you could start to think about making those injectable into the helper class using a common handler-interface.